# How to embed a conf file along with python script into my .exe file

Tags: python-3.x, setup.py

I am trying to create a .exe file from my existing pyhton script and it's conf file. The conf file contains sensitive information and hence can't be distributed outside of the binary.

So the requirement is:
[as per this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv0dR.png)

Comment: you do realise that this sensitive information can be unpacked or disassembled for people wanting to get to it anyway??

Comment: I understand that. But just wanted to know how people tackle this kind of scenario. Any suggestion/help is appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

> First thing PyInstaller does is to build a spec.
> That file is stored in the --specpath= directory, by default the current directory.
>
> You can add binary files to the bundle by using the --add-binary command option, or by adding them as a list to the spec file

```
a = Analysis(...
     binaries=[ ( '/usr/lib/libiodbc.2.dylib', '.' ) ],
     ...)
```

or directly in the console

```
pyinstaller --add-binary '/usr/lib/libiodbc.2.dylib:.' myscript.py
```

See [this](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/spec-files.html)

Comment: @Zoe better now?

Comment: Yeah. I've retracted my flag